# Angular TypeScript how to assign Date

Tags: angular, angular-daterangepicker, angular-bootstrap-calendar

How can i bind date to date selector?

```js
const TodayDate = "19-11-2020";
ngOnInit() {
  this._MyregisterForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    today_Date:[this.TodayDate, [Validators.required]]
  });
}
```

HTML

```html
<form [formGroup]="_MyregisterForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input type="date" formControlName="today_Date" value="{{TodayDate}}">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to put `value` attribute in input when are using `formControlName`

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-typescript-how-to-asign-date?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="_MyregisterForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <input type="date" formControlName="today_Date">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, VERSION } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { DatePipe } from "@angular/common";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
  providers: [DatePipe]
})
export class AppComponent {
  _MyregisterForm: FormGroup;
  TodayDate = "19-11-2020";

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private datePipe: DatePipe) {
    this._MyregisterForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      today_Date: [this.getTransformedDate(this.TodayDate), Validators.required]
    });
  }

  private getTransformedDate(date) {
    let date1 = date.split("-");
    let newDate = date1[2] + "-" + date1[1] + "-" + date1[0];
    return newDate;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const date = this.datePipe.transform(
      this._MyregisterForm.get("today_Date").value,
      "dd-MM-yyyy"
    );
    alert(date);
  }
}
```

Comment: formControlName="todat_Date"  is not Binding My Date

Comment: change your date format in YYYY-MM-dd like "2020-11-19"

Comment: Excellnt Buddy Keep it up Thank you Soo much For your Help

Answer (score 0):

Remove `value="{{TodayDate }}"` You're binding a control with TodayDate value and that's enough.

Comment: Date Is not Binding to my DatePicker

Answer (score 0):

I would try to keep the dates as javascript dates in your app.
It will make it easier to format them differently and use them with angular materials date picker.

use the library date-fns to parse the string into a date.

https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/parse

Then pass that date into the formBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

I provide a Stackblitz [just here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zsjkmv?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

The date format is not good, you need to use International format.
Moreover, like everyone said, you don't need to bind a `value`.

```
_MyregisterForm: FormGroup;
TodayDate = "2020-12-10";

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  this._MyregisterForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    today_Date: [this.TodayDate, Validators.required]
  });
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="_MyregisterForm">
    <input type="date" formControlName="today_Date">
</form>
<pre>{{ _MyregisterForm.value | json }}</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

`TodayDate` should be;

```js
TodayDate = new Date();
```

and remove `value` attribute from `input`